# Wikimapia API for Python (PyMapia)

Tags: python, wiki, wikimapia

I am trying to use **pymapia** API for Wikimapia made for Python and not able to understand about how to use it properly.

```
import pymapia as PyMapia
a = PyMapia.PyMapia.get_all_categories()
```

It gives me the error as following.

> TypeError: unbound method get_all_categories() must be called with
>   PyMapia instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

I am not sure whether I am using it properly with all arguments. I have also generated the **key** for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pymapia.PyMapia` is a class. You need to create an object which is an instance that class, and then call the object's methods.

Try this:

```
#UNTESTED

import pymapia as PyMapia
session = PyMapia.PyMapia("Your_Api_Key_Goes_Here")
a = session.get_all_categories()
```